# SessionExpiredException error in android JSON

Tags: android, json, session, ssl, json-rpc

In android RESTFUL webservice,

1. In  `HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();` - **I get successful response.**
2. But Now my URL changed to http to https(SSL). - **And this url not trusted certificate.**

so I use following @Daniel code.

[Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https?rq=1)

3. If I Use `client = WebClientDevWrapper.getNewHttpClient();` instead of `DefaultClient()` - **I get sessionExpiredException error.**

any help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are using this method

```
public void connect() throws Exception  {

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(new URI(""));
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(""));
        trustAll();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse result = client.execute(post);
    }
```

Add this code before the HttpsURLConnection and it will be done.

```
private void trustAll() { 
    try { 
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){ 
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { 
                            return true; 
                    }}); 
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 
            context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){ 
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, 
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {} 
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, 
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {} 
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
                            return new X509Certificate[0]; 
                    }}}, new SecureRandom()); 
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory( 
                            context.getSocketFactory()); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.e("TAG",e); 
    } 
}
```

this method worked for me to accept the certificates and also try increasing the session time out.

Comment: first try this then try passing hostname and boolean this worked for me.

Comment: your code work for login page url. But I get session expired in main page url. I use same session id.